# Как я могу проверить свою репутацию?

Tags: поддержка, faq, репутация

- Если я подозреваю, что моя репутация подсчитана неправильно, как я могу её проверить?
- Могу ли я где–либо посмотреть подробный отчет о моей репутации?

<sub>Перевод статьи «[How do I audit my reputation?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43004/274323)».</sub>

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Убедитесь, что вы вошли в систему и откройте следующую страницу:

```
http://sitename.com/reputation
```

Например:

- https://ru.stackoverflow.com/reputation
- https://stackoverflow.com/reputation
- https://meta.stackexchange.com/reputation

Вы получите подробный отчет о вашей репутации, со статистикой на текущий момент времени. Выглядит это примерно следующим образом:

```
2     29812 (2)
-- 2009-11-15 rep +245  = 28647     
2     29877 (10)
3     29886 (-2)
1     29877 (15)
2     29886 (10)
2     27958 (7)
2     29905 [0]
1     29905 (15)
3     29884 (-2)
2     29521 (2)
2     31021 (5)
2     29878 [0]
9     28065 (550)
-- 2009-11-16 rep +275  = 28922     
1     29915 (15)
3     29882 (-2)
```

<sub>Выше приведен пример статистики, а не реальный отчет.</sub>

**Первое число** – это тип голосования из следующего перечня:

- 1 = принятый ответ (вам или от вас)
- 2 = голос «за» (вам)
- 3 = голос «против» (вам или от вас)
- 4 = штраф за публикацию, которую отметили как оскорбление
- 8 = награда за участие в конкурсе (присуждаемая вами)
- 9 = награда за участие в конкурсе (присуждаемая вам)
- 12 = штраф за публикацию, отмеченную как спам
- 16 = одобренное предложение об исправлении

**Второе число** – идентификатор сообщения, с которым ассоциировано событие. Помните, что голосование за общие сообщения на репутации их авторов *не* отражается. Как результат, голоса за общие сообщения в этом отчете не учитываются. Некоторые типы голосования – «оскорбление», «спам», «конкурсные» – применимы к любому сообщению, независимо от того, имеет ли оно статус общего.

**Третье число** – ценность голоса. Учтите, что ценность может быть «заморожена» (зафиксирована без возможности повышения), если вы уже достигли *дневного максимума голосов* за повышение репутации. При фиксировании этого параметра соответствующее число появляется в квадратных скобках, например: `[3]`.

**Временные рамки** – выводятся, если  в течение определенного временного промежутка ваша репутация изменилась. Здесь указаны текущая дата, количество баллов, на которое изменилась (увеличилась или уменьшилась) ваша репутация по сравнению с предыдущим показателем и общий уровень репутации на данный момент.