# Интересные вопросы новых участников сообщества

Tags: обсуждение, поддержка

Этой публикацией стартует серия сообщений, призванная выделить наиболее интересные вопросы заданные новыми участниками сообщества. В «список» попадают первые вопросы на сайте новых участников сообщества Stack Overflow на русском.

Некоторые публикации серии будут содержать раздел «Бюллетень сообщества», в котором будут кратко подчеркнуты выделяющиеся события (необычные ответы, интересная статистика и другие данные).

«Изюминкой» публикаций должен стать «вопрос к сообществу» – вопрос на произвольную тему, каким–либо образом относящийся к программированию, сообществу или ИТ–отрасли в целом. Если хотите задать интересующей вас «вопрос сообществу», отправьте его мне почту (вопрос будет опубликован анонимно).

---

#### 24 Августа – 4 Сентября

### Интересные вопросы

- [Практическое применение Enum](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/559045/6) от участника [SweetDev](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/218370/).
- [Как использовать спецификаторы формата?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/558655/6) от участника [Rocky55](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/218281/).
- [Почему появляется ошибка undefined?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/559403/6) от участника [lesha310392](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/218455/).
- [Изменение каждой нечётной строки теста на странице](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/561596/6) от участника [Aivengo](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/218936/).

### Бюллетень сообщества

В сообществе давно появился интерес к проведению теста измененных причины закрытия, где в качестве короткого описания будет использоваться заголовок причины, а не призыв к действию – «[Временное обновление заголовков причин закрытия вопросов](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3639/)». В будущем, если вы хотите улучшить причины закрытия вопросов или их формулировки, пожалуйста, предварительно прочитай [предыдущие обсуждения на Мете](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1936/). Прекрасным примером подобной революционной деятельности может служить вопрос «[Проблемы причины закрытия “опросник” и возможные решения](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1918/)». Для сообщества правильные причины закрытия [крайне важны](http://data.stackexchange.com/ru/query/528650#graph)!

Несколько полезных [faq](/questions/tagged/faq)–вопросов.

- [Как работает репутация?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3663/)
- [Как я могу проверить свою репутацию?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3539/)
- [Как устроена система конкурсов?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3618/6)

### Вопрос к сообществу

> *Какой следующий язык или технологию вы бы хотели изучить? Почему именно этот язык/технологию, а не другие?*

Comment: Интересные вопросы выбираются автоматически, исходя из числа голосов или это вручную отобранный редактором список?

Comment: @AK Вручную отобранные на основе критериев. Основной критерий – сумма голосов за вопрос, количество ответов и количество голосов в ответах. Буду рад, если вы предложите более интересную формулу!

Comment: А что дальше будет с вопросами к сообществу?

Comment: @andreycha видимо ожидается получать на него ответы в этой теме, т.к. в общем подобные вопросы не соответствуют тематике SO, ибо "основаны на мнениях". Если я всё правильно понял.

Comment: @alexolut Да, совершенно верно!

Comment: Т.е. я правильно понимаю, что логика следующая: есть некоторые вопросы, интересные сообществу, но в ruSO они не укладываются, потому что "основаны на мнениях", поэтому мы будем обсуждать их на Мете? В чем логика? Сколько человек читает ruSO, и сколько Мету? Не лучше ли аккуратно разрешать подобные вопросы на самом ruSO? Ведь те же вопросы о проектировании и архитектуре -- всегда основаны на личном опыте и мнении. Но тем не менее это важные и полезные вопросы, и обсуждения их тоже полезно. (К счастью, закрывается лишь меньшая часть таких вопросов.) Не лучше ли нам подумать в этом направлении?

Comment: Все подобные вопросы, как я понимаю, обычно задаются на http://programmers.stackexchange.com. Мы раньше обсуждали тот факт, что не может себе позволить разные сообщества на русском, и поэтому тематика ruSO сейчас несколько шире, чем enSO. Так может нам еще расширить ее и на "скользкие" темы, которые обсуждаются в сообществе programmers?

Comment: @andreycha Как мне кажется, можно пока посмотреть как инициатива будет жить на здесь, на Мете.

Comment: "Технологии/языки" предлагается публиковать ответами, так?

Comment: @D-side Да, именно!